# Plotting using 'colorbar' in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plotting

I am trying to plot a figure similar to the one attached here,I tried searching how to do a similar kinds of  plot and i found about 'colormap','colorbar' in MATLAB.

Actually I want to plot this situation -

There are $1000$ cars indexed by $i=1,2,3,...,1000$ and the position changes as a function of time,now i plot index versus time and the pair(time,index) plots a value(here a colour) that is position.

[image]

But I am unable to find similar kind of plotting technique, any example on how to do this kind of plots in MATLAB or reference would be very much helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "searching on a plot"? What are you planning to do? Why is the colorbar not helping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot you have shown was probably created using [imagesc](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html). The colors were choosen with the [colormap](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) command and the color bar is shown with [colorbar](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html).